# Автоматическое добавление IP маршрутов Windows

Tags: windows, сеть, windows-7, маршрутизация

Компьютер подключён к сети, допустим 192.168.0.0/24. Есть VPN-подключение к другой сети 192.168.10.0/24.

Как сделать так, чтобы при подключении VPN автоматически добавлялся маршрут к сети 192.168.40.0/24?

Понимаю, что можно было бы сделать так:

```
route add -p 192.168.40.0 mask 255.255.255.0 <IP VPN>
```

Проблема в том, что  - меняется при каждом подключении.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо создать триггер на создание VPN-соединения. Если не изменяет мне память, то при установке соединения средствами Windows в журнале событий "Приложение" появляется запись от источника "RasClient" с соответствующим номером **Event ID**. 
Нужно создать задачу на запуск **route.exe** с необходимыми параметрами. Можно через оснастку "Планировщик заданий". Созданная задача должна запускаться от пользователя **SYSTEM**. Для этого она скрытно выполняется вне зависимости от регистрации пользователя и с наивысшими правами.
При выдаче Вам IP адреса, думаю, адрес шлюза всегда один и тот же на VPN-интерфейсе. Вот и укажите его как *IP VPN* для команды **route**